# How to display an .rtf file in a Powershell RichTextBox

Tags: powershell, richtextbox, rtf

I want to display the content of an RTF file in a Powershell RichTextBox.

I am trying to make a kind of custom EULA, and the easiest way to do it would be to write the content in an RTF file and then have it display in a RichTextBox on my form, so the user has to click a checkbox to accept it.

(I'm sure this sits between ServerFault and StackOverflow, but I'm guessing the DotNet gurus on here will know best. ;-) )

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - that was easy. Should have got my lazy ass on Google a bit more before posting. Used `RichTextFile.Loadfile(c:\myfile.rtf)` and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else happens upon this wondering where the PowerShell [RichTextBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) came from it's a reference to the one in System.Windows.Forms. Here's the code with prerequisite build up:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$rtb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$rtb.LoadFile($path)
```